# How can I combine all using UnderscoreJS, Omit and few conditions?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, functional-programming, underscore.js, chaining

```
const objA = {
    name: 'jack',
    age: '24',
    address : '#210-1101',
    zip : '10114',
    Zip1 : '22222',
    accountNo : '12345667890',
    bankName : 'KB',
    amount : '1000',
    currency : 'USD',
    country : 'USA'
  };
  
  const objB = {
    name: 'eddie',
    lastName : 'bauer',
    addressDetail : '',
    address: '#210-1101',
    zip: '10114',
    currency : 'EUR',
    country : 'FRA'
  };
  
  const isSame = (v,k) => objA[k] === v;

  const tmpRet =  _(objB).omit(isSame);

  const isName = (tmpRet, k) =>  k === 'name' ? Object.assign(tmpRet, {date: '19780708'}, {}) : '';

  const isCurrency = (tmpRet, k) => k === 'currency' ? Object.assign(tmpRet, {currency2: 'USD'}, {}) : '';

  const checkCondition = (tmpRet, k) => { isName(tmpRet, k); isCurrency(tmpRet, k); };

  const goFunc = () => _(tmpRet).each( (v,k) => checkCondition(tmpRet, k));

  goFunc();
  console.log(tmpRet );
```

I have a code something like above and I just can not put them all together.

I want to make it more of a functional way and one-liner.

Any suggestions??

Thanks

Comment: Your code does not work `_(objB).omit(isSame)`. What did you mean here?

Comment: @captain-yossarian I am using underscore and isSame(predicate) is the function above to just check where the value is same or not. My intention of this code is to find different key, value from objB comapring objA. Using omit function to find the different properties and according to certains keys need to add extra property

Comment: Sorrry, my bad...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

YOu probably looking for smth like this:

```js
import _ from "underscore";

const objA = {
  name: "jack",
  age: "24",
  address: "#210-1101",
  zip: "10114",
  Zip1: "22222",
  accountNo: "12345667890",
  bankName: "KB",
  amount: "1000",
  currency: "USD",
  country: "USA"
};

const objB = {
  name: "eddie",
  lastName: "bauer",
  addressDetail: "",
  address: "#210-1101",
  zip: "10114",
  currency: "EUR",
  country: "FRA"
};

const compose = (...fns) => (tmp, k) =>
  fns.reduceRight((acc, fn) => fn(acc, k), tmp);

const isSame = (v, k) => objA[k] === v;

const omit = (obj) => _(obj).omit(isSame);

const hasProperty = (obj, prop) =>
  Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop);

const isName = (tmp) =>
  hasProperty(tmp, "name")
    ? {
        ...tmp,
        date: "19780708"
      }
    : tmp;

const isCurrency = (tmp, k) =>
  hasProperty(tmp, "currency")
    ? {
        ...tmp,
        currency2: "USD"
      }
    : tmp;

const goFunc = () => compose(isName, isCurrency, omit)(objB);

const result = goFunc();
```

I believe you can skip the iteration through the each key

Comment: Thanks, @captain-yossarian I like your approach with an array of functions... 
but your fns.reduceRight((acc, fn) => fn(acc,k), tmp) won't accumulate the changes. 
So, I've changed it like fns.reduceRight((acc, fn) => Object.assign( acc, fn(acc, k)), tmp)

Comment: Do you have different ideas to accumulate changes??? 

expected result is like below..

{
  name: 'eddie',
  lastName: 'bauer',
  addressDetail: '',
  currency: 'EUR',
  country: 'FRA',
  date: '19780708',
  currency2: 'USD'
}

Comment: and the goFunc... I've changed to only send keys.. like below..

const goFunc = () => _(Object.keys(tmpRet)).each(k => compose(isName, isCurrency)(tmpRet, k));

Comment: Nice... 

const hasProperty = (obj, prop) =>
  Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop);
about this one... can you explain to me?? instead of using obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) ? 
Thanks

Comment: Sure, here you have nice explanation https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-prototype-builtins